# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. (while displaying date time..)

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

While executing following error is showing

```
declare @yr_mnth_dt as numeric;
set @yr_mnth_dt = 20130822;
select convert(datetime,@yr_mnth_dt,112) as YR_MNTH_DT
```

error shows

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

Comment: I've normally seen convert expressions like that dealing with *strings* rather than numbers. Do you have to start with a numeric type?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You issue is that you're trying to `convert` the numeric to a `datetime`, and this just isn't working.

You need to turn your `numeric` into a string first:

```
declare @yr_mnth_dt as numeric;
set @yr_mnth_dt = 20130822;

select yr_mnth_dt = cast(cast(@yr_mnth_dt as char(8)) as datetime);
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19418).

When you try and convert a numeric type to a `datetime`, SQL Server tries to add the numeric value as the number of days to the date `01-Jan-1900`. In your case this is trying to add millions of days, and hence the overflow error.

`CONVERT` works fine, too, if you prefer:

```
select yr_mnth_dt = convert(datetime, convert(char(8), @yr_mnth_dt));
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/19425).

Answer (score 3):

I've only seen the conversion used for strings. I can't easily tell whether it's even designed to work with numbers. You *could* convert the number to a string, then the string to a date. However, I would personally just use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(@yr_mnth_dt / 10000, 
                     (@yr_mnth_dt / 100) % 100,
                     @yr_mnth_dt % 100) AS YR_MNTH_DT
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but worth noting it's SQL Server 2012 and above only.

Comment: @IanPreston: Hadn't noticed that. *Surely* there's some way of creating a date from its constituent parts prior to that without using a string...

Answer (score 2):

Why numeric?
Try this

```
declare @yr_mnth_dt as varchar(10);
set @yr_mnth_dt = '20130822';
select convert(datetime,@yr_mnth_dt,112) as YR_MNTH_DT
```

Comment: According the comments from the OP he has to start with a `numeric` type.

Comment: @Ian Preston,
but I see that it is august 22, 2013, not the integer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Now we can do simply:

```
declare @yr_mnth_dt as numeric;
set @yr_mnth_dt = 20130822;
select cast(str(@yr_mnth_dt) as datetime); // output: 2013-08-22 00:00:00.000
```