# SQL Server: datetime error

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    CRS, Total_Balance,
    Subcategory,
    Date_Last_Updated,
    DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Last_Updated) AS Expr1
FROM 
    dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_CO_SH
GROUP BY 
    CRS, Total_Balance, Subcategory,
    Date_Last_Updated, DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Last_Updated)
HAVING 
    (Subcategory = 'Transfer to Workout')
    AND (DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Last_Updated) = 2016);
```

and here is the error message:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.

Can you please guide me to correct it?

Comment: what is the datatype and the values of Date_Last_Updated column?

Comment: Date_Last_Updated is  DATETIME

Comment: What is the advantage of using the date column in grouping ? Do you want the data grouped by date ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. (while displaying date time..)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416623/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-datetime-while-di)

Comment: The following may help you see the records of interest to the root data cause.    SELECT        CRS, Date_Last_Updated 
FROM            dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_CO_SH
WHERE (ISDATE(Date_Last_Updated) = 0) 
  AND Date_Last_Updated IS NOT NULL

Comment: please share any value that `Date_Last_Updated` contained

Comment: @SqlSurfer, `ISDATE()` returns 0 for `datetime2` as well. Might not be an all inclusive test (still not bad to try, of course).

Comment: Can you post `sp_help 'dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_CO_SH'` ? Meanwhile clean your query: you dont need to group by `DATEPART(YEAR, Date_Last_Updated)` because you group by the field itself; both conditions should be in where condition; and finally, as @HoneyBadger says, a `distinct` is faster if you dont need aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too long for a comment...

Could you try:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT CRS
,         Total_Balance
,         Subcategory
,         Date_Last_Updated
,         YEAR(Date_Last_Updated) AS Expr1
FROM      dbo.Transfer_Final_Accounts_CO_SH
WHERE     Subcategory = 'Transfer to Workout'
    AND   YEAR(Date_Last_Updated) = 2016;
```

You are using `group by` without aggregates. It's better practice to use `distinct` in that case.

That being said, I still can't tell for sure where your error originates...(If Date_Last_Updated is indeed a `datetime` as you say, that is.)