# How to convert timestamp to date&time in SQL?

Tags: sql

Table have one column which contain timestamp value.I want to convert that timestamp value to date&time in SQL.

When I using like this

```
select cast(1520339311 as datetime)
```

I'm getting an error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime

How to handle that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime. (while displaying date time..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18416623/arithmetic-overflow-error-converting-expression-to-data-type-datetime-while-di)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119386/how-to-convert-sql-servers-timestamp-column-to-datetime-format

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: `1520339311` is not a timestamp, that's an integer. A timestamp is `2018-03-13 10:26:00`

Comment: Ok.Can u pls give me solution to convert it

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's TIMESTAMP datatype has nothing to do with a date and time!
See the links Below:

[CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

[rowversion (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql)

[Already Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119407/9449683)